# How do I enable Windows Authentication on a Web API when using WebApplicationFactory for Integration Testing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, integration-testing

In ASP Net Core 3.0, how do I enable Windows Authentication to my WebAPI when using WebApplicationFactory to create Integration Tests.  Setting up the Test Host to Allow Anonymous requests is not an option due to the fact that my Domain Layer requires valid user information to perform systematic audit logging of all write requests and will throw an exception (by intention) if the UserPrincipal cannot be validated.

Thank you very much in advance for the assistance!